# Handle NPM warning about Bootstrap's 'unmet peer dependency' when they are not used in Angular

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, npm, bootstrap-4, yarnpkg

I'm using Angular 5.2.0 together with Bootstrap 4 in my web project. I installed bootstrap 4 via `npm i bootstrap --save` and it told me about unmet peer dependencies:

```
npm WARN bootstrap@4.0.0 requires a peer of jquery@>=3.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN bootstrap@4.0.0 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.11.0 but none was installed.
```

Of course, Bootstrap's JS relies on these peer dependencies. So far, so usual.

The thing is: I don't use any of Bootstraps JS. I'm using [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home) which are the Bootstrap Components rewritten for Angular.

This warning annoys me, because it really isn't a thing, when I'm not using it anyway (and nobody else in this project should - getting an error when trying to use Bootstrap's components natively is perfectly fine). Clean code and dependencies should not output any warnings.

To get rid of this warning, I tried different :

- *Find an npm-package which only contains Bootstrap's SCSS.* [There is at least one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-sass) but it still uses Bootstrap's version 3. Furthermore, there is no way to tell, when these packages get updated, so I prefer to use the original `bootstrap` package.
- *Just install the dependencies and not use them.* This results in dependencies in the `package.json` which are not used - and should (imho) also be avoided in a Clean Code environment.
- *Silence the warnings from yarn/npm (I'v recently switched to yarn, but the errors are similar).* Probably not a good idea, warnings are usually useful... There seems to be also [consensus](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5253), that one should not be able to switch off specific warnings. I kinda agree.

  - *Ignore them*. Not an option for me - as mentioned above, a clean build proess should not return warnings.

So: **Is there any way to handle these peer dependency warnings in a clean manner?**

Comment: just ignore them, if the code builds fine and displays how it should, ignore it

Comment: I really want a way to surpress this warning so that I can more cleanly see real warnings.  Glad I'm not the only one.  "Just ignore the warning" is shameful software craftsmanship (this frustrated comment directed at npm, not at any person).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, the real answer is that we need to just ignore the warnings.

The creator of `ng-bootstrap` explicitly states that the warnings are our only option due to technical reasons in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51838216/2738164).  They also mention that you shouldn't install the `jquery` or `popper.js` dependencies due to potential conflicts ([per the setup docs](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started)).