# ng-bootstrap dependancies and warning

Tags: bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I wish to use ng-bootstrap.

The documentation ask to install bootstrap CSS as dependency, but do not include jQuery

if I install bootstrap with npm I get warning that it need jquery and popper.

```
$ npm i -S bootstrap
npm WARN bootstrap@4.1.3 requires a peer of jquery@1.9.1 - 3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN bootstrap@4.1.3 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.14.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

Is there a way to install bootstrap css in my project without adding unwanted peer dependencies ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having a missing peer dependencies warning on jQuery / popper is normal at this point. The reason for this warning is that ng-bootstrap only needs Bootstrap CSS. It doesn't require Bootstrap JS nor its dependencies (popper.js).

We can't get rid of this warning, unfortunately, as Bootstrap does *not* publish packages that would have CSS only. The only way to install Bootstrap CSS is to to install the whole package that has peer dependencies set to jQuery / popper.

To cut the long story short: this warning is expected and there are technical limitations preventing us from getting rid of it. You do not need jQuery / popper to use ng-bootstrap and you should not install those manually. You should also ignore missing peer dependencies warning at this point.

Comment: Yes, ng-bootstrap works properly for me... I was hoping get rid of those warning... but the answer is I should bear it :-/ . Thanks for the feed back.

Answer (score 1):

just try this in Window:

```
npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

just try this in Linux:

```
sudo npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```